# 3 duplicated symbols for architecture i386

Tags: objective-c, xcode

After I try to build my app with Xcode, this error appear:

```
     duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_StoreVars._Traguardo in:
    /Users/Fede/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProvaTapChallenge-bqumsaqmowwbdfbzgzrrwlblxsgh/Build/Intermediates/ProvaTapChallenge.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProvaTapChallenge.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
    /Users/Fede/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProvaTapChallenge-bqumsaqmowwbdfbzgzrrwlblxsgh/Build/Intermediates/ProvaTapChallenge.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProvaTapChallenge.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewControllerBase.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_StoreVars in:
    /Users/Fede/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProvaTapChallenge-bqumsaqmowwbdfbzgzrrwlblxsgh/Build/Intermediates/ProvaTapChallenge.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProvaTapChallenge.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
    /Users/Fede/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProvaTapChallenge-bqumsaqmowwbdfbzgzrrwlblxsgh/Build/Intermediates/ProvaTapChallenge.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProvaTapChallenge.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewControllerBase.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_StoreVars in:
    /Users/Fede/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProvaTapChallenge-bqumsaqmowwbdfbzgzrrwlblxsgh/Build/Intermediates/ProvaTapChallenge.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProvaTapChallenge.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
    /Users/Fede/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProvaTapChallenge-bqumsaqmowwbdfbzgzrrwlblxsgh/Build/Intermediates/ProvaTapChallenge.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProvaTapChallenge.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewControllerBase.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

how can i solve this? help me, please!

Comment: This typically means you have multiple StoreVars classes and it does not know which one to compile against. Under your file organizer in Xcode, on the bottom you can type in a file name, do this and it should come up with all of the files named StoreVars, from here hopefully you will see more than one and can remove the files you do not want.

Comment: thanks Joel, but it doesn't work.. there's only a file named StoreVars..

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you've accidentally imported StoreVars.m file instead of StoreVars.h